# What's difference between ex and ex-mode tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are two tags [ex](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ex) and [ex-mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ex-mode).

However I'm not quite sure what's the difference?

Is [ex](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ex) indicates the command-line (`ex` tool), and [ex-mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ex-mode) means working in Ex mode (`vim -E`)? Isn't it the same?

If it is, should we remove questions from [ex](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ex) and stick to [ex-mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ex-mode) only?

As far as I remember, I haven't created [ex](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ex) so that's why I'm confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `ex` is an editor; it's the direct predecessor of `vi`.
- ex mode is a "mode" in Vim, which emulates `ex`.

This can be seen by `vi(1)` for example:

```
NAME
       vi, view, vedit - screen oriented (visual) display editor based on ex

[...]

       Vi (visual) is a display oriented text editor based on ex(1).   Ex  and
       vi  run  the same code; it is possible to get to the command mode of ex
       from within vi and vice-versa.
```

And `ex(1)` says:

```
Ex is the root of a family of editors: edit, ex and vi.  Ex is a super‐
set of ed, with the most notable  extension  being  a  display  editing
facility.  Display based editing on CRT terminals is the focus of vi.
```

In Vim, Ex-Mode may 'emulate' ex(1), but you [usually](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2694/51) still have many of the Vim extensions (including plugins) and so forth...

The difference is somewhat subtle... But in general, I would recommend:

- Use [ex-mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ex-mode) for questions about using Vim's ex mode (this will probably be the overwhelming majority of the questions).
- Use the [ex-command](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ex-command) for questions about `ex`

If we only had the [ex](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ex) tag, there would be no obvious way to tag questions about `ex`...

Comment: Thanks, my `man ex` redirects me to `man vim` so doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: @kenorb By the way, I left [this question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/51) tagged as `ex` originally, but I just tried the `ex` commands, I none of them actually work with `ex` (only with Vim ex mode), so it's not really a question about "ex", as such...

Comment: If a question about ex(1) comes up, it would be best to name its tag [tag:ex-command] or [tag:ex-utility] or [tag:ex-program] or something distinctive like this, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Possibly a bit late to change now, but I would've voted against `ex-command` for the name and in favour of one of the other suggestions, because the phrase "Ex command" is often used to refer to any of the commands you type into command-line mode. (e.g. see the first sentence of `:help user-commands`).